# Can we please stop telling people to use "apt-get" when simply "apt" accomplishes the same thing?

Tags: support, answer-format, answering

It's just bad advice to give to tell people to type in longer codes than are necessary. Think of all the wasted seconds spent typing that extra `-get` that could be spent on other things. Yes, some apt codes are slightly different, but lets learn those differences instead of making people waste their time due to not wanting to learn them.

Comment: Is it really that big a deal? Like you say, they accomplish the same thing, but it's a four-character difference. I don't know your typing speed, but the average person could probably do that in under 0.5 seconds. Until `apt-get` is officially deprecated, I don't think it's "bad advice" in any way to use `apt-get` in an answer.

Comment: Time is money. There's no reason to waste time pointlessly. I guess you just can't see the reasoning behind what I'm saying... (a problem, not a solution!)

Comment: @TheWanderer I don’t think `apt-get` is any more deprecated than `apt` itself. @OP I think you got the right idea, often `apt` is the better alternative for users. However, if the command is presented on the site, most people will copy and paste it anyway – I don’t see the typing as a problem, but I think the more user-friendly output of `apt` justifies using it. @all As to the differences and uses of both, see [apt gives “Unstable CLI Interface” warning](https://askubuntu.com/q/990823/507051).

Comment: Your comment is a total nonsequitor, @dessert, and so of course it has plenty of thumbs up.

Comment: the little difference between `apt` and `apt-get` is about the display bar/purcentage display; some people prefer `apt-get` prompt, so that's why we see on some tutorial the use of `apt-get`, but they do exactly the same work ! N.B: there is also `aptitude`, but it's not installed by default now and is very long to write, but that's another (which personnally, I don't like it)

Comment: @damadam [Aptitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software)) is mainly a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) application, although it has a few CLI use-cases.

Comment: @Melebius I mean, you have to open it (aptitude) from the terminal just the same way, it just uses different interface... semantics.

Comment: @dessert that's what I said. `apt-get` isn't deprecated, so why stop using it?

Comment: I use aliases to get 'round "Think of all the wasted seconds spent typing that".

Answer (score 11):

Even when keeping in mind [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get) there is still no logical reason to enforce using `apt` over `apt-get`/`apt-cache`.  An extra second or two to type 4-6 extra characters is not a major inconvenience and **the vast majority of users** are not going to care if they're typing `apt` versus `apt-get` so long as it gets the job done of what they're intending to do.

---

There may also be other factors at play, such as **how used to a specific command being typed** someone is.

If I am writing answers, I tend to use `apt-get` because I've been using Ubuntu since 9.04 and it's ingrained in me that that's the command to use for command line management of installed packages.  Yes, `apt` can do the same thing, but in *my* case it's muscle-memory and a habit to write out `apt-get`.

If Joe Smith is used to using `apt` and not `apt-get` and has a user write out `apt install ...` instead of `apt-get install ...` then that's their preference, and they're probably used to using `apt`.

---

**Ultimately, however,** it's a matter of preference to what the user who posts a given answer/question uses as to which the answer may use for its commands.  `apt` or `apt-get` both work, and **neither** are deprecated to the point they don't work, so users can use *either of them* in answers depending on their preference.

As I said earlier, **there's no logical reason to enforce the usage of one or the other**.  After all, **the vast majority of users** are not going to be inconvenienced by a single second or two's worth of extra typing.

Comment: No. they are gonna care. They just don't know that `apt` exists. Of course they would want to use it if they knew what it was, they don't want to waste time just like every other reasonable person on the planet! As soon as I heard `apt` was a thing, I made a note to myself like "I will never use apt-get again since I don't need to, its a waste of time." many other people would take note of that if they only knew about it.

Comment: nobody *enjoys* wasting extra seconds of time every day on pointless stubbornness. So lets not wrong our fellow user by wasting their time. It's very simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 10):

We all know the difference:

- [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get)

Both have their merit as both work for the task they are designed to.

This also means there is no reason why we should force people into one or the other.

Comment: yes, there is a reason to ask that people help their fellow users by helping them not waste time. As I've already stated, it's a waste of time to type the extra `-get` when it is not necessary.

Comment: @Emandudeguy the **overwhelming vast majority of users** are not going to care that it takes an extra second or two to type a few extra characters.  You may care about that, but the vast majority of other users don't.

Comment: Not to mention, dessert makes a great point that most people just copy and paste the commands presented. If we're going to start distinguishing between the time it takes to copy a command with `apt` and one with `apt-get`, we're going to need a proverbial electron microscope.